# How does Geordi read and work with numbers?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Geordi's VISOR images, as seen in "The Mind's Eye" and a couple other episodes, are not the clearest pictures in the world. Individuals are fuzzy, for example, which leads me to ask: How does Geordi read? While working at his Engineering station, how does he see and deal with small numbers and figures on the console? Wouldn't the words and numbers be illegible?

Comment: Very related to  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36107/why-does-geordi-la-forges-visor-see-a-wide-subspace-spectrum-and-not-just-visib